# how to see less recent packages on pypi

Tags: python, pypi

I saw some really interesting packages on pypi yesterday. They've fallen off the list today and (being senile) I don't recall enough detail to get to them. How do I get a list of all packages for (say) the last week?

Comment: If you briefly indicate what's wrong with the question, I'll upvote your downvote :)

Comment: Ultimately, this isn't really a programming question and thats why someone downvoted it. This is more of a software request. Your best option is to ask the admins at pypi directly.

Comment: I appreciate the info. I figured an API approach the likely answer, but if a URL was available that'd have done. Turns out some programming was needed to answer :) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPi has an xmlrpc API. You can get a list of recent releases with an `updated_releases` method. It returns a list of releases made since given timestamp.

For example, it may look like this:

```
import xmlrpclib
import time

client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("https://pypi.python.org/pypi")

interval = 86400*2
for package, version in client.updated_releases(int(time.time()) - interval):
    print "%s %s" % (package, version)
```

Additionally there is a `release_data(package_name, release_version)` method to get more details about particular release

Comment: Very beautiful solution...much obliged!

Comment: A little scan through from that script got the relevant package for me: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xpyth/0.1.0

Comment: This was the other interesting one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mozrepl/1.2.4 (I think the descriptive text is Korean, but it looks very useful from the code examples). Both found with your script, "grep moz" and a flaky memory!

Comment: import xmlrpclib
    import time

    client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("https://pypi.python.org/pypi")

    days_back=1
    interval = 24*3600*days_back
    for package, version in client.updated_releases(int(time.time()) - interval):
        print "%20s : %s" % (package,client.release_data(package, version)['summary'])

Comment: Sorry! trying and failing to do a code-block. You get the idea.